# iOS App signing for non-AppStore distribution without needing UUIDs

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I see companies like Hailo, Uber and such distribute apps outside the App Store (ie to drivers: https://hailocab.com/ireland/drivers/blog/2013/07/26/re-downloading-hailo-driver-app)

I know you can generate an 'Ad Hoc' provisioning profile with number of UUIDs of devices for it to run on, but how could you create a distribution provisioning profile that could go on any number without needing UUIDs ahead of time? Do you need an enterprise account?

Answer (score 0):

they use the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: ... which is fine as long as the users downloading are contracted to that company - hence making it an exclusive "in-company-distribution".

Comment: Of course, the Enterprise Program should be for employees distribution only, you must provide the security to make sure nobody outside your company can use it